# How can I import a vector drawing into Google Slides?

Tags: google-drive, google-slides

Google Slides adds an annoying amount of compression on my imported images. I want to avoid compression so I want to upload my schematics in a vector format. I can basically export myself to any vector format possible.

How do I do this in Google Slides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you still have this issue or for others and for future reference, there is a way to do this through the later versions of Microsoft Power Point.

1. Save your vector graphics in **.svg** preferably. If they were produced
   using Adobe Illustrator, don't forget to outline your text
   (<kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>), and `Strokes`, as well as `make Compound`.
   `Paths` of the shapes like circles and rounded squares etc.
2. `Import` your svg in a Power Point presentation through the standard `Insert Image` option.
3. Right click on the image and select `Convert to Shape`.
4. `Save` the Power Point and proceed to your Google Slides document.
5. Select `File > Import Slides`, upload you PP presentation, select the slide with the image.
6. You can now select, copy, and paste the vector version of your image as if it had been done with shapes in Google Slides :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to upload an svg directly and via [url](http://www.lonniebest.com/CardTrick/image/JB.svg). Uploading an svg produced an [invalid image error](http://neartalk.com/ss/2018-10-08_003_2111x1300.png) and the [by URL method](http://neartalk.com/ss/2018-10-08_001_2096x1300.png) didn't work either.

The only thing I believe you can do link to the vector file:

[image]

Comment: I just noticed I got confused between Slides and Sheets. I'm talking about Slides, sorry!

Comment: Oh, ok. No problem.

Comment: I tried to accomplish the same thing in slides for you, I got the exact same results as in sheets above (exact same error messages). I also looked for slides-addons that might do it, but didn't find anything. This surprises me; I'd think vector images would be supported, because it would give the best quality.